# How to pass Apache Kafka Mirrormaker2 config for the producer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently testing Mirrormaker to replicate data between two clusters. Unfortunately it seems the producer config is not utilized by the individual producers then as documented in https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/mirror/README.md.

My configuration file simplified:

```
clusters=INPUT,BACKUP
                                     
INPUT.consumer.compression.type=lz4       
BACKUP.producer.compression.type=lz4
                            
INPUT->BACKUP.enabled = true                       
INPUT->BACKUP.topics=mytopic.*
...
```

Then the log output when running mirrormaker2 (`connect-mirror-maker.sh mirrormaker.properties`) does not show this option:

```
INFO ProducerConfig values:
        ...
        compression.type = none
        ...
```

The Kafka version in use is 2.7.1.

How can I pass the settings correctly, so the producer is correctly compressing? I also need to pass a few other settings, but once this works it should do for the other settings too.

Answer (score 0):

Two potential solutions:

1. Enable `connector.client.config.override.policy` in mm2 workers' property file. You need to follow https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-the-worker-configuration closely.
2. Launch a Kafka Connect cluster and create `MirrorSourceConnector` and `MirrorCheckpointConnector` one by one with producer configs overridden. You will still need to refer to the official Confluent documentation above. I picked this approach and it works.

Comment: Thanks @wenli-wan, I tried with the solution 1 above but it does still not seem to take the option in. I tired a few different ways (prefixing with INPUT/BACKUP etc) but to no avail. Would you be able to post a full config for the first approach, I want to keep it simple and not necessarily fire up a connect cluster.

Comment: I chose the 2nd approach and it works, but I didn't have a chance to try the 1st one.